# How to download large files when the download size is restricted?

Tags: networking, download

**?** In my office, the network admin has restricted the download limit to a size of 1.8MB for any file. This is for sub ordinates accounts only. But for my manager's PC, there are no restrictions. Is there any way to download files from my PC by using my managers' ip address. I just tried using his ip on my pc but, had the same problem.

**?** Earlier I was given access to our Linux server from my pc using putty. Then I used to download large files on to the server and then transfer from server to my machine using fire ftp. This transfer worked perfectly fine. But, now I don't have any access to the server. So can I be able to download large files using fire ftp from my own PC ?

I'm using Windows XP machine.

Please suggest a solution by any possible combination. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Ask your network admin to raise your quota. Obviously if it is in place it has been approved by management and trying to go around it will probably get you disciplined or ever terminated. If there's a real reason, they should make an exception for you. If there isn't a good reason, they won't.

The download limit is probably some kind of FS Quota or third party GPO extension that is based on user accounts or machine accounts. Using his IP won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid reason for your download madness you should ask your network administrator. If you don't have a reason for the large file downloads I suggest you stop downloading files from work before you lose it.

There is no way around this restriction that I can think of, besides logging in as your manager.

Download files from home instead. It's worth not losing your job.